# Datetime from year and week number

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format

I have a year and a week number which I want to convert into a `datetime.datetiem` object. My (naive?) reading of the documentation hinted that `strptime('2016 00', '%Y %W')` should do just that. However:

```
In [2]: from datetime import datetime

In [3]: datetime.strptime('2016 00', '%Y %W')
Out[3]: datetime(2016, 1, 1, 0, 0)

In [4]: datetime.strptime('2016 52', '%Y %W')
Out[4]: datetime(2016, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So it turns out that the week number isn't enough for `strptime` to get the date. Add a default day of the week to your string so it will work.

```
from datetime import datetime
myDate = "2016 51"
datetime.strptime(myDate + ' 0', "%Y %W %w")
datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 25, 0, 0)
```

The 0 tells it to pick the Sunday of that week, but you can change that in the range of 0 through 6 for each day.

Comment: how can I turn this into 2016-12-25?

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) (see note 7 at the bottom):

> When used with the `strptime()` method, `%U` and `%W` are only used in
>   calculations when the day of the week and the year are specified.

Thus, as long as you don't specify the weekday, you will effectively get the same result as `datetime.strptime('2016', '%Y')`.