# Converting integer values to week (year-week format)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am trying to convert one of the dataframes I have to year-week format to use it in my time series modeling, but I am not sure how would I be able to do this?

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
c=15
s={'week':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],'Sales':[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80]}
p=pd.DataFrame(data=s)
```

Output-

[image]

Desired O/p in week column should be in date time format.

[image]

The datatype was an int in the 1st dataframe, but needs to be in datetime, where 2021 is year and 1 is week. (1st week of year 2021)
How would I be able to do this?

Comment: You can already use a `datetime` in time-series modeling. Did you just want to _format_ your output as `%Y-%W`?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi It's probably that. DateTime format won't allow year-week.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi yes it needs to be in %Y-%W, if it would be possible to do so.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38528515/datetime-from-year-and-week-number

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Datetime from year and week number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38528515/datetime-from-year-and-week-number)

Comment: @FObersteiner, it was helpful but the below answer was spot on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.apply()`:

```py
import datetime
p['week'] = p['week'].apply(
    lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(f'2021-{x:02}-1', '%Y-%W-%u')
)
```

This outputs:

```
        week  Sales
0 2021-01-04     10
1 2021-01-11     20
2 2021-01-18     30
3 2021-01-25     40
4 2021-02-01     50
5 2021-02-08     60
6 2021-02-15     70
7 2021-02-22     80
```

Comment: I'm a bit hesitant to do so, as the expected output doesn't match `datetime`'s usual format as Pranav states. If you can resolve that ambiguity in the original question, it would make it easier for future readers to understand what the question is really about, and then I'd be happy to give an upvote.

Comment: since the OP is using pandas: you have [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), which I think would make for more readable and concise code compared to the apply + native Python datetime usage.