# How to create rrule occurrence for even weeks

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, week-number, python-dateutil, rrule

I am using rrule from python-dateutil 2.8.2 in python 3.10 to generate datetimes.

I can't figure out how to create a rrule that creates outputs for only even week numbers.

It seems like the "byweekno" parameter might be able to do this, but I haven't been able to find any examples that explain how to only output from even weeks.

Edit 1:
Unfortunately there is no guarantee that my "dtstart" is in an even week, which means that using "interval" would not be helpful as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking it over some more, I used the following rule:

```
list(rrule.rrule(freq=WEEKLY, byweekday=MO, byhour=12, byweekno=range(2, 54, 2), dtstart=datetime.datetime(year=2023, month=3, day=11), until=datetime.datetime(year=2023, month=5, day=31)))
```

... to create biweekly outputs:

```
[datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 20, 12, 0), datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 3, 12, 0), datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 17, 12, 0), datetime.datetime(2023, 5, 1, 12, 0), datetime.datetime(2023, 5, 15, 12, 0), datetime.datetime(2023, 5, 29, 12, 0)]
```

Using range to create a list of the 26 even week numbers feels a bit brute force for my taste, so I would love it if somebody else could suggest a more elegant approach.

Answer (score 0):

This construct should work:

```
In [23]: list(rrule(freq=WEEKLY, interval=2, count=5))
Out[23]: 
[datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 6, 15, 45, 35),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 20, 15, 45, 35),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 3, 15, 45, 35),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 17, 15, 45, 35),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 1, 15, 45, 35)]
```

You will just need to kick it off on whatever (even) week you want by setting the `dtstart` argument to the correct date.  That, is described in this answer:

[Datetime from year and week number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38528515/datetime-from-year-and-week-number)

Comment: Using "interval" makes sense if you can tweak "dtstart" to be in an even week. Unfortunately in my case other factors influence "dtstart", which does not guarantee an even start week. I have modified my question to clarify that limitation.