# YYYY-WNN format to "%d/%m/%Y" date format

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

Hi i have a pandas columns named YearWeekISO that has the YYYY- WNN date format, for instance 2020-W53. I want to convert that whole column to a date time format of
day-month-year.

This is the code i am using:
pd.to_datetime(df['YearWeekISO'], format="%Y-W%U").dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

This is the error output:
Cannot use '%W' or '%U' without day and year

Thanks,best regards

Comment: Perhaps this link will help>>>[Year and Week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38528515/datetime-from-year-and-week-number).

Answer (score 0):

Set up the day of week:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['YearWeekISO']+'0', format='%Y-W%U%w').dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

Output:

```
  YearWeekISO       date
0    2020-W53 03/01/2021
```

Comment: I´ve tried that but the data "2020-W53" turned into "03/01/2021", and the years are different. Do you know why?

Comment: @André this is how ISO week numbers are working. W53 can define the first few days of the next year. `2020-W53` is spanning  `2020-12-28 (Mon)` to `2021-01-03 (Sun)`.
 See [ISO week date](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) for reference.